# How to get gradient wrt to a specific layer's output pytorch

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

The idea behind this is I want to try some old school gradient ascent style visualization with Bert Model.

I want to know the effect of input on a specific layer's specific dimension. Thus, I took the gradient of the output of a specific layer's specific dimension wrt the first word embedding layer's output.

The best thing I can do here is the following:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_attentions=True,output_hidden_states=True)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_version, do_lower_case=True)
s = 'I want to sleep'
inputs = tokenizer.encode_plus(s,return_tensors='pt', add_special_tokens=False,is_pretokenized=True)
input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
output = model(input_ids)
hidden_states = output[-2]

X = hidden_states[0] #embedding space, shape: [1,4,768] (batch_size,sentence_length,embedding dimension)
y = hidden_states[3][0][0][0] ##the 0th position and 0th dimension of output of 3rd hidden layer. Dimension should just be [1], a scalar.

torch.autograd.grad(y,X,retain_graph=True, create_graph=True) #I take the gradient of y wrt. Since y is scalar. The dimension of the gradient is just the dimension of X.
```

This is, however, not good enough. I want the gradient wrt the actual word embedding layer. However, Transformer's embedding contains "position_embedding" and "token_type_embedding". Here's the code for the first layer embedding:

```
class BertEmbeddings(nn.Module):
    """Construct the embeddings from word, position and token_type embeddings.
    """
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(BertEmbeddings, self).__init__()
        self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(config.vocab_size, config.hidden_size, padding_idx=0)
        self.position_embeddings = nn.Embedding(config.max_position_embeddings, config.hidden_size)
        self.token_type_embeddings = nn.Embedding(config.type_vocab_size, config.hidden_size)

        # self.LayerNorm is not snake-cased to stick with TensorFlow model variable name and be able to load
        # any TensorFlow checkpoint file
        self.LayerNorm = BertLayerNorm(config.hidden_size, eps=config.layer_norm_eps)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.hidden_dropout_prob)

    def forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids=None, position_ids=None):
        seq_length = input_ids.size(1)
        if position_ids is None:
            position_ids = torch.arange(seq_length, dtype=torch.long, device=input_ids.device)
            position_ids = position_ids.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(input_ids)
        if token_type_ids is None:
            token_type_ids = torch.zeros_like(input_ids)

        words_embeddings = self.word_embeddings(input_ids)
        position_embeddings = self.position_embeddings(position_ids)
        token_type_embeddings = self.token_type_embeddings(token_type_ids)

        embeddings = words_embeddings + position_embeddings + token_type_embeddings
        embeddings = self.LayerNorm(embeddings)
        embeddings = self.dropout(embeddings)
        return embeddings
```

Ideally, I want the gradient wrt JUST “words_embeddings" Rather than, wrt "words_embeddings + position_embeddings + token_type_embeddings" and follows by layerNorm and dropout.

I think I can do this by modifying changing the model. Is there a way to it without changing the model?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar. But I do not understand why do you have to do this? ```y = hidden_states[3][0][0][0]```. Can you explain this line a little bit? For example if I am trying to get the grad for layer 1 w.r.t to the output (let's say word "sleep"), why do I have to check the output of layer 3? Shouldn't it be 1, the next layer?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. Notice y is my "output", not the input where I took the gradient with respect to. I think your output is some classification task instead. The whole point I am asking this question is trying to find if the hidden state of BERT has semantic meaning. We found the latent space of BERT is unlike CNN, has no semantic meaning. One needs to use some statistical method to separate our those semantic meaning. For those of you who are interesting, this is our effort to separate our those semantic meaning: https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15949